PostgreSQL: Making breaking changes in relational Database between app versions - how to rollback?
Assume that I am doing some refactoring in app's code that uses some relational database. It was decided that some columns and tables are not required from domain perspective, require renaming or have changed structure in code and DB. So I make changes in the code and alter the DB via migration script applied on app's deploy.
Now all is great, app is released as v1.1.0 and after some time Product Owners decide that we must roll back to the old version while keeping the data in the DB. Of course it will fail, because the DB has breaking changes in its schema.
How do you approach this problem?
Let's assume 2 scenarios: 'small' change (like rename a column) vs. 'bigger' refactoring (reorganize structure of tables)
Thanks

Treat it as you did when making the breaking changes, because that is what you are doing.

When making changes to a product, it is important to maintain backward compatibility. For database changes you just have to come up with a strategy for each kind of change. For example:
For a Column rename
   - Add a new column with the new name
   - Retain the old column 
   - Migrate data from old column to the new one during deployment
   - New app version uses the new column and old version continues to use the old column.
   - At EOL of the old version, remove the column

You can come up with similar steps for every kind of breaking database changes. The idea is to let the old version continue to work until its EOL.

This could work on small databases, not on large databases. And how are you going to keep referential integrity when a table or column doesn't exists in one version but does in the other? Or a unique constraint that does exist in one version but not in the other?
